# Nonhomogeneous 2nd Order Differential Equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with solving this nonhomogeneous 2nd ODE

$$x^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}+x\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}-y=x$$

In order to get the general solution I rewrote the equation like this

$$x^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}+x\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}-y=0$$

Then I assumed that $y=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is a constant. When I plugged this into the 2nd equation I got

$$\alpha (\alpha -1)x^{2}x^{\alpha-2}+\alpha x^{\alpha-1}x-x^{\alpha}=0$$

The general solution was

$$y=C_{1}x+C_{2}x^{-1}$$

and then I got confused as to what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let $y=e^t$ and establish the relation between $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the advice. You know that $y'=\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}$ and $y''=\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}$, therefore, we will have
$$
x^{2}y''+xy'-y=x,
\\
x^{2}y''+2xy'-xy'-y=x,
\\
(x^{2}y')'-xy'-y=x,
\\
(x^{2}y')'-(xy)'=x,
\\
(x^{2}y'-xy)'=x.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still not able to find the solution. I tried to plug in $y=Ax+B$ to your final equation but didn't get anything. I am not sure as to how should I use it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach towards the characteristic equation should have as next step the cancellation of $x^α$ so that $α^2-1=0$ remains. This gives basis solutions $x^1$ and $x^{-1}$. Did you mistake $1$ for $t$ or is this some method to get the special case for the particular solution from a more general case?

As the right side repeats one basis solution, the particular solution will have the form $y_p=Ax\ln x$.

Comment: I mistook 1 for t in this case.

Comment: Ok. It is however a valid strategy to change the right side to $x^t$, find $\frac{x^t}{t^2-1}$ as one particular solution that is singular for $t\to1$, modify it with the homogeneous solution to $\frac{x^t-x}{1-t^2}$ where the limit exists, via l'Hopital or mean-value theorem.